# Java Float to "remove" comma

Tags: java, int

I need to convert a float to an int, as if the comma was removed.
Example:
23.2343f -> 232343

```
private static int removeComma(float value)
{
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {
        if((value * (float)Math.pow(10, i)) % 1.0f == 0.0f)
            return (int)(value * Math.pow(10, i));
    }
}
```

The problem is with rounding up of the number. For example if I pass 23000.2359f it becomes 23000236, because it rounded up the input to 23000.236.

Comment: Couldn't you just use `(int)(value * 10000f)` or `Math.floor(value * 10000f)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Java float doesn't have that much precision, which you can see with

```
float f = 23000.2359f;
System.out.println(f);
```

which outputs

```
23000.236
```

To get the output you want, you could use a `double` like

```
double d = 23000.2359;
String v = String.valueOf(d).replace(".", "");
int val = Integer.parseInt(v);
System.out.println(val);
```

Output is (the requested)

```
230002359
```

Comment: Good workaround. You could add to the answer for how many digits this does work without errors. I think it's 15 or 16.

Comment: Thats pretty good, but what if there is an e behind the number? (2343.4323e2 -> 23434323e2 -> Integer.parseInt exception)

Comment: @RandomNoob Then you would need to use an algorithm like you posted in your question. But what you can't do, is assume that `double` and/or `float` have infinite precision (because they don't).

Answer (score -3):

you must find a way to get the number of digit after decimal place 1st. Suppose it is n. then multiply the number with 10 times n

```
double d= 234.12413;
String text = Double.toString(Math.abs(d));
int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
int decimalPlaces = text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
```

Comment: Simple question: why?